# 2 Binary Equal php files, one works while the other emits White Screen of Death

Tags: php

I edited the `<title>` in a php file (myfile.php) then re-uploaded it to the server; that is all I changed.

Now navigating to that page/file doesn't work. I get php's White Screen of Death (view-source is blank too).

I then renamed that file locally and reuploaded it as `myfile2.php`.

TaDa. It works.

I've already restarted the server and the original file still won't work.

Comment: If you compute the checksum (md5/sha1) of the files, are they different?

Comment: The problem is fixed now (view my answer below); I had run kdiff on the 2 files and it determined that they were binary equivalent. So the CONTENTS were equivalent..but obviously something else was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that while myfile.php file was binary equal to myfile2.php something got messed up on the server. **Deleting** the original myfile.php and then reuploading it fixed it.

Comment: sounds like it was likely a permissions issue.

Comment: agreed. I'm not too keep on how file access works on Linux but I'm thinking I may have refreshed the page causing the server to try to access the file right as the newer version of the file was finishing being written...so some how the setting of permissions got interrupted in the process. *Shrug*